# hive group-by dealing with empty values

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

Suppose I am using Hive to group by a column, and the column could have value 1, 2, 3 or empty, wondering if I just need to simply write group by `<column name>` to handle empty values?

The purpose of my analysis is to count how many rows have value 1, 2 3 and empty individually.

BTW, the type of the column is string.

thanks in advance,
Lin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "empty" you mean `NULL`, then, yes, you can use `group by`.  This query:

```
select col, count(*)
from table t
group by col;
```

will return a separate row for `NULL`.

Comment: thanks. Besides NULL, "empty" has other meanings? My column in this case is a string type. :)

Comment: You will get a separate row for each value.  That is, the `group by` does not do any filtering.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff, for all NULLs, it will be a single row, correct?

Comment: @LinMa . . . Yes.  `GROUP BY` treats `NULL`s as being the same value.  You can argue with the ANSI committee, but this is how all databases work.